# Adobe pdf services sdk

Tags: python

I am trying to run this project from github, https://github.com/adobe/pdfservices-extract-python-sdk-samples
i downloaded the project.
got the credentials
ran the pdfservices-extract-sdk==1.0.0b1 api and dependencies

now i am trying to call the program extract_txt_from_pdf.py to convert pdf to document, i got the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "extract_txt_from_pdf.py", line 35, in 
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.auth.credentials import Credentials
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adobe'

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `pip install adobe` first

Answer (score 1):

As I found, you will need to pre-install the below module separately to properly install `pdfservices-sdk` module in your system.

FYI: Minimum requirement is python 3.6 as of today

```
pip3 install Sphinx
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Per the instructions [here](https://opensource.adobe.com/pdftools-sdk-docs/release/latest/index.html#python), you need to:

1. Extract the downloaded samples .zip.
2. From the samples root directory, run pip install -r requirements.txt.
3. Test the sample code on the command line.